# Getting MQ error (reason 2594) when trying to connect to MQ manager after first few messages

Tags: java, websphere, mq

I am upgrading a standalone Java app that uses IBM MQ to send messages to a local Websphere 8.5 server. The existing app uses a bunch of different jars for the MQ code (mq, mqbind mqjms, connector-api, jms).

For the new one I saw that there is now an all-encompassing "allclient" MQ JAR (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient/9.2.0.0) so I decided to use that.

It appears to work just fine for the first few messages, but after sending 4-5 messages, all subsequent messages will then fail with a code 2594 (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q120510_.htm):

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2594;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(5558)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2594;AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=WAS.JMS.SVRCONN     ]],3=localhost(5558),5=RemoteConnection.initSess]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13588)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.access$100(RemoteFAP.java:13125)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1430)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1389)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:916)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:240)
```

On the server side, I get the following in the console:

```
CWSIC3712E: A WebSphere MQ client, previously connected from host 127.0.0.1:58963 on transport chain InboundBasicMQLink, has been disconnected because of exception java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
```

After this error occurs, any subsequent attempts to send a message will fail with the same error. I have to restart the app at which point the same thing repeats: first 4-5 messages send before the fails begin. If I switch back to using the old JARs without changing the code, I'm able to send an unlimited number of messages without any issues.

The reason code is confusing to me ("An MQCONN or MQCONNX call was issued from a client connected application, but it failed to agree a password protection algorithm with the queue manager.") because if it's truly a password issue, why do the first couple messages send without issue? It does not seem to be an issue with closing/disconnecting the queue/manager because I'll wait a few seconds between each send and can breakpoint/println and see that each time they are being closed before the next send.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you see in the queue managers `AMQERR01.LOG`?  If you check the queue managers `qm.ini` file do you find a `PasswordProtection=` line and if so what is it set to?  Since the error indicated channel negotiation failed, are you sure the first few messages sent are actually received on a queue?  Have you tried setting the connection factory property `USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` to true?  (or alternately the java system property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication` to `Y`.

Comment: From your error it looks like you have a queue manager running on this `localhost(5558)'`.  can you run "dspmqver" on a CMD prompt, look for `DataPath` and look under there for `qmgrs/QmgrName/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` and `qmgrs/QmgrName/qm.ini`.  Please cleanup the comments above that  are no longer needed, if not the moderators will move this to chat and I don't have access to chat.

Comment: Here's what I get from dspmqver: InstName: Installation1     
InstDesc:  (blank)    
DataPath:    C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ  (the ProgramData folder doesn't even exist)

Comment: So my `InstPath` points at `C:\Program Files\IBM\Websphere MQ`. That - and its sub-folders - don't contain any *.log and the only *.ini are examples under under `\samp\` folders like `mqclient.ini` `mqs.ini` and `\Tools\c\Samples\mqat.ini` and `\Tools\c\Samples\mqccred\mqccred.ini`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The websphere application server is created within and run from an Eclipse java workspace.

Comment: To connect to MQ you need a MQ server software and queue manger defined.  You mentioned you verified messages were on the queue.  The queue is part of a queue manager.  The logs I asked about would be on the server where the queue manager is "running".

Comment: @JoshMc, I found a workaround of sorts which I've posted as the answer. It however causes problems of its own. Perhaps you can take a look and it might give you some insight as to what else might be going on that is causing problems in my workspace?

Comment: finding the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG and seeing what error is displayed may help to find the root cause.  You mention connecting to `localhost(5558)`, so it would seem the queue manager is on the same server where WAS is running?  Try `C:\Program Files\IBM\Websphere MQ\qmgrs\QueueManagerName\errors\AMQERR01.LOG`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial workaround to this problem:

In the Java code, for our MQMessage object, we declare a "replyToQueueName". If I remove that setter, the problem seems to go away (we can send as many messages as we want without error).

I'm not certain why in this particular case that seems to work. The failure that occurs happens on the MQQueueManager declaration which is much higher up in the code than the replyToQueueName setter. This combined with this bug only occurring after 4-5 messages are sent seems to maybe indicate that something is not being "closed" properly but as far as I know there is no way to "close" a message and we are already closing/disconnecting the manager and the queue.